# Why is the cdc_list getting updated after calling the function read_csv() in total_list?

Tags: python

**# Program to combine data from 2 csv file**
*The cdc_list gets updated after second call of read_csv*

```
overall_list = []  
def read_csv(filename): 

    file_read = open(filename,"r").read()  
    file_split = file_read.split("\n")  
    string_list = file_split[1:len(file_split)]  
    #final_list = []  
    for item in string_list:  
        int_fields = []  
        string_fields = item.split(",")  
        string_fields = [int(x) for x in string_fields]  
        int_fields.append(string_fields)  
        #final_list.append()  
        overall_list.append(int_fields)  
    return(overall_list)   

cdc_list = read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")  
print(len(cdc_list))  #3652

total_list = read_csv("US_births_2000-2014_SSA.csv")  
print(len(total_list)) #9131  
print(len(cdc_list)) #9131
```

Comment: Not sure, but why aren't you using the built in CSV library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), or something even better like Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for data manipulation?

Comment: I have just started with python from DataQuest and got stuck with this code.
Anyways...Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code you pasted explains the issue you've had, at least it's not anywhere I can determine. Seems like there's a lot of code you did not include in what you pasted above, that might be responsible.

However, if all you want to do is merge two csvs (assuming they both have the same columns), you can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)' [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and Pandas DataFrame methods [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), to achieve this with 3 lines of code (not including imports):

```
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame object
df = pd.read_csv("first.csv")

# Read and append the 2nd CSV file to the same DataFrame object
df = df.append( pd.read_csv("second.csv") )

# Write merged DataFrame object (with both CSV's data) to file
df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.